# Delphi + ADO + dBase

Tags: delphi, ado, dbase

I'm trying get these 3 to work nicely. If I use this connection string

```
Driver={Microsoft dBASE Driver (*.dbf)};DriverID=277;OLE DB Services = -1;Extended Properties=dBase IV;Dbq=c:\mypath
```

doing operations like `ADOTable1.Open` are very fast (good) but `GetIndexNames` returns nothing (bad).

If I use instead this connection string

```
Provider=Microsoft.Jet.OLEDB.4.0;Extended Properties=dBASE IV;OLE DB Services=-1;Data Source=c:\mypath
```

doing operations like `ADOTable1.Open` are exceedingly slow (bad) while `GetIndexNames` does return index names the way it should (good).

How do I get both speed and the index info via ADO for the dBase tables?

Answer (score 2):

We use the following connection string which works really well.

```
Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties="Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};UID=;SourceDB=c:\mypath;SourceType=DBF;Exclusive=No;BackgroundFetch=Yes;Collate=Machine;Null=Yes;Deleted=Yes;"
```

Comment: I'm going to give that a shot and report back. Thanks!

Comment: Inside the IDE when I put this string in the property editor for TADOConnection.ConnectionString and try to flip the Connected property to True I pop an error -> "[Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver does not support this function". I'm pretty sure I have all other properties at their defaults. Mode is cmUnknown. CursorLocation is clUseClient. IsolationLevel is ilCursorStability. ConnectOptions is coConnectUnspecified. I have remembered to put in my own path for SourceDB. Anything I might be missing?

Comment: Have you checked that the Provider property is set to "MSDASQL.1"? You could try removing some of the options?

Comment: I took out everything I could and ended up with this: 'Provider=MSDASQL.1;Extended Properties="Driver={Microsoft Visual FoxPro Driver};SourceDB=c:\mypath;SourceType=DBF;"' and still get the same error. I can't see eliminating anything else. And yes, the Provider property is properly set by the action of putting that entire string in the ConnectionString edit box.